# How to install R extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install R extension for Visual Studio Code by Yuki Ueda. In the [support page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r&ssr=false#overview), it states as first step for installation

> For Windows, set config **r.rterm.windows** to your **R.exe** Path like **"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.4\bin\x64\R.exe**";

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quite mysterious instructions refer simply to the setting in the R extension in Visual Studio Code. To set this value to the R executable path, these are the steps in VS Code 1.35.1 on Windows.

> File > Preferences > Extensions

Right click on the R extension and Configure Extension Settings.

In the R > Rterm: Windows cell, paste the path to the R executable.